# Space between BottomAppBar and Keyboard

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomappbar

I am having a issue with BottomAppBar and SoftInputKeyboard..

I have a form like this : 
[image]

Now i have used BottomAppBar and BottomNavigationView for the menu options on it.

Here is the what i have done.

> ```
> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>     <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
>         android:id="@+id/appbar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
>         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
>
>         <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
>             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
>
>                 <TextView
>                     android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>                     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>                     android:gravity="center"
>                     android:textSize="16sp" />
>             </RelativeLayout>
>         </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
>     </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
>
>
>     <fragment
>         android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
>         android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar"
>         app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
>
> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
>
> <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
>     android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>     android:clickable="false"
>     app:fabAlignmentMode="center"/>
>
> <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
>     android:id="@+id/fab"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
>     app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_bar" />
>
> <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
>     android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>     app:elevation="0dp"
>     app:menu="@menu/home" /> </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
> ```

Now When I try to fill information in the editText, and keyboard opens up. It looks like this :

[image]

There's an unusual gap between keyboard and bottomAppBar. I want to keep the scrolling behaviour when user fills information, as we have more fields in this form.

I want to remove it. What am I missing here!! Can anyone please help me out?

In manifest, I have

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: hello everyone I was missing one point here. i have to set android:fitsSystemWindows="false" in my coordinator layout, earlier it was set to true.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, setting `android android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` works very well. I had the same problem, but now it is fixed.